# Setting a certain location when using pafy

Tags: python, download, pafy

This is my code:

```
import pafy 

url = "youtube_url_here"
vid = pafy.new(url)
reso = vid.getbest()
reso.download()
```

Could anyone tell me how to set a location to save the video in instead of the working directory?, also how to make the program ask me what resolution I want to download ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation of `pafy`](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/) you will find that you can pass a `filename` parameter to the `download()` function:

```py
reso.download(filepath="/tmp/video." + reso.extension)
```

This is a Linux path though, so you might adjust it to use a Windows file path instead.

Comment: Ok thanks , but how about how I make it ask me for each resolution

Comment: @LastFox this belongs to another question. And I don't know